# Datepicker not working when included in another JSP file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

I have a file Inside.jsp which is included in the file total.jsp. I have an inputfield in Inside.jsp. When you click in it a calendar is supposed to appear on the screen. If you are in the browser at http://localhost:8080/inside.jsp the calendar opens but if you are in http://localhost:8080/total.jsp nothing happens (the calendar doesn't open instead it's just a normal input field). What can I do to fix that?

I belivee that it has something to do with my scripts or links but it would be good to get an explanation.

Inside.jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" name="viewport"
    content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/total.css">
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script
    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>


<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#pickdate").datepicker();

    });
</script>


<title>Inside</title>
</head>

<body>

<input type="text" id="pickdate" class="form-control">


</body>
</html>
```

Total.jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link
    href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/total.css">



<title>Total</title>
</head>

<body>


    <divt><jsp:include page="Inside.jsp" /></div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js></script>

    <script
    src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're actually including a complete HTML page inside another, with the head and body parts which are already in the Total.jsp page, 
To solve such an issue the inside.jsp should remain clean.. just the content you want, and you should move the libraries and css loading to the Total.jsp.

And leave the inside.jsp with only fields and that script which associates datepicket to the field.

Total.jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link
    href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/total.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>

<title>Total</title>
</head>

<body>


    <divt><jsp:include page="Inside.jsp" /></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Inside.jsp:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#pickdate").datepicker();

    });
</script>

<input type="text" id="pickdate" class="form-control">
```

Comment: Thank you. Good explanation. Good to know for anyone who includes a jsp or HTML file.